# Is there an API for getting app prices in the Google Play/App store?

Tags: data-request, api

I'm looking for an API that can get me prices for apps. I also want information on in-app purchases given the ID (package name in Android) of the app.

An example query would be:

Query:

```
ID: identifier of the application
COUNTRY: country to look for (some applications have price depending on country)
```

Response:

```
PRICE: price of the app in the country (0 if it's free)
IN_APP: true if the app has in-app purchases, false otherwise
PRODUCTS: dict object having name of the in-app product as key and the price as value
```

I did some research on the web. I found the [42matters](https://42matters.com/app-market-data) API. However, it's only approximating the price of in-app products (I verified with one of my apps) giving a somehow large range, e.g.

```
[in_app_min:0.99, in_app_max:144.99]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two unofficial Google Play APIs. You'd have to build your own dataset, or expand the API to get the fields you want.

**https://github.com/egirault/googleplay-api**

```
$ alias pp="column -s ';' -t"

$ python search.py earth | pp

Title                           Package name                            Creator                  Super Dev  Price    Offer Type  Version Code  Size     Rating  Num Downloads
Google Earth                    com.google.earth                        Google Inc.              1          Gratuit  1           53            8.6MB    4.46    10 000 000+
Terre HD Free Edition           ru.gonorovsky.kv.livewall.earthhd       Stanislav Gonorovsky     0          Gratuit  1           33            4.7MB    4.47    1 000 000+
Earth Live Wallpaper            com.seb.SLWP                            unixseb                  0          Gratuit  1           60            687.4KB  4.06    5 000 000+
```

**https://github.com/facundoolano/google-play-scraper/**

Example:

```
var gplay = require('google-play-scraper');

gplay.app({appId: 'com.dxco.pandavszombies'})
  .then(console.log, console.log);
```

Results:

```
{
  appId: 'com.dxco.pandavszombies',
  title: 'Panda vs Zombie: Elvis rage',
  summary: 'Help Rocky the Panda warrior to fight zombie games and save the Panda kind.',
  url: 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dxco.pandavszombies&hl=en',
  icon: 'https://lh6.ggpht.com/5mI27oolnooL__S3ns9qAf_6TsFNExMtUAwTKz6prWCxEmVkmZZZwe3lI-ZLbMawEJh3=w300',
  minInstalls: 10000,
  maxInstalls: 50000,
  score: 4.9,
  reviews: 2312,
  histogram: { '1': 12, '2': 7, '3': 16, '4': 40, '5': 231 },
  description: 'Everyone in town has gone zombie.',
  developerId: "DxCo+Games",
  descriptionHTML: 'Everyone in town has gone <b>zombie</b>.',
  developer: 'DxCo Games',
  developerEmail: 'dxcogames@gmail.com',
  developerWebsite: 'http://www.dxco-games.com/',
  developerAddress: '10685-B Hazelhurst Dr. # 18457\nHouston, TX 77043\nUSA',
  updated: 'May 26, 2015',
  genre: 'Action',
  genreId: 'GAME_ACTION',
  familyGenre: undefined,
  familyGenreId: undefined,
  version: '1.4',
  size: '34M',
  androidVersionText: '2.3 and up',
  androidVersion: '2.3',
  contentRating: 'Mature 17+',
  price: '0',
  free: true,
  screenshots: ['https://lh3.ggpht.com/le0bhlp7RTGDytoXelnY65Cx4pjUgVjnLypDGGWGfF6SbDMTkU6fPncaAH8Ew9RQAeY=h310']
  video: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/PFGj-W8Pe5s',
  comments: ['Great! Its a great time waster'],
  recentChanges: [ '- Added a hint system' ],
  preregister: false
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @philshem, these APIs don't provide information on in-app products. The information is available in the app store (not in the Google play) I'm looking for an API to retrieve this kind of information e.g clash of clans
In-App Purchases 


Pile of Gems $4.99
Bag of Gems $9.99
Sack of Gems $19.99